# Quadprog violating constraint

Tags: r, optimization, quadratic, convex-optimization, quadprog

Hello I am trying to solve a quadratic constrained optimization problem using Quadprog package in R. However the non negativity constraint is getting violated

```
 library(quadprog)
options(scipen=999)
A=c(0,0,0,0)
Amat=cbind(diag(1, length(A)), rep(1, length(A)), rep(-1, length(A)))

bvec=c(rep(0, length(A)), 1, -1)

Dmat=matrix(c(2.00044131893129, 2.00049178814425,   2.00041839697958,   2.00030559324023,   2.00049178814425,   2.00064972136399,   2.00053994496836,   2.00037532914833,   2.00041839697958,   2.00053994496836,   2.00049628996226,   2.00032367551724,   2.00030559324023,   2.00037532914833,   2.00032367551724,   2.00031018936379)
,nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
Dvec=c(2.00014726495946,    2.0002164445682,    2.00016868307137,   2.00014845293229)
Opt_quad=solve.QP(Dmat,Dvec,Amat,bvec)
```

However the output is coming neagtive

Comment: I don't know what exactly confuses you, but if it is the first entry of the solution vector, `-1.641119e-18` can be considered `0`. It is a case of numerical imprecision.

Comment: Actually the output is negative also. While i am giving the constraints as all variables to be non negativ

Comment: That's part of that same imprecision. If it is 0, it doesn't matter that it is -0 does it?